# jquery .change() on multiple select keeps firing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the selected values(s) from a multiple select element and do a AJAX call if only single option is selected. The problem is, `.change()` keeps firing if any option other than default is selected. Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.pwpus-field-loop-post-types').each(function() {

    var div = $(this).parent().siblings('.taxos-block');
    var ajaxImage = $(this).siblings('.pwpus-field-loop-taxoloader');

    $(this).change(function() {
      var sel = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected');
      //Log length
      console.log(sel.length);

      if (sel.length == 1 && $(sel).attr('value') != 'all') {

        $(div).css({
          'opacity': 0
        });
        $(ajaxImage).fadeIn();

        var data = {
          'action': 'pwpus_loop_taxes',
          'type': $(this).val(),
          'name': $(this).attr('data-fieldname'),
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
          $(ajaxImage).fadeOut(function() {
            $(div).html(response).css({
              'opacity': 1
            });
            $(document).trigger('typetaxesdisplayed');
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pwpus-field-loop-inner-wrap">
  <div class="pwpus-field-loop-single-field">
    <select name="scattrloop[post_type][]" class="pwpus-field-loop-post-types" data-fieldname="scattrloop" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="all" selected="selected" class="selectall optionselected">All</option>
      <option value="post">Posts</option>
      <option value="pwpreviews">Reviews</option>
      <option value="deals">Deals</option>
    </select>
    <img class="pwpus-field-loop-taxoloader" src="/admin/assets/images/ring.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="pwpus-field-loop-single-field taxos-block"></div>
</div>
```

My firebug console is going haywire if I select any other options than 'all'. I have no clue where I am doing wrong. Tried several answers here, like unbinding the change event prior to calling it or even use `.off()`.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by going haywire? Is it doing something other than `console.log(sel.length)`?

Comment: The `.change()` method runs whenever you select or unselect something.

Comment: @Barmar it automatically keeps logging `sel.length` plus showing the AJAX request the `.change()` keeps making once in every second. The `.change()` method keeps firing automatically whenever I manually trigger it by selecting something.

Comment: I converted your code to a stack snippet, and I don't see it doing anything except when I click on an option.

Comment: I just created a fiddle and strangely it's working there too..https://jsfiddle.net/itsabhik/oj3awz78/7/ Not sure whats causing in this on my server.

Comment: Are you loading any other libraries on the real page?

Comment: @Barmar, nope!! Just jQuery, WordPress bundled version.

Comment: Got a link you can share?

Comment: Well, its on WordPress Admin dashboard..

Comment: I need a link I can go to from here to debug.